# Matching two files in OCaml

Tags: exception, pattern-matching, ocaml

I am trying to check to see whether some two files are the same and wrote the following code.

```ml
let print_test_success input1 input2 =
  let ic1, ic2 = open_in input1, open_in input2 in
  let rec loop i1 i2 =
    match (input_line i1, input_line i2) with
    | string1, string2 -> if String.trim string1 = (String.trim string2)
                          then loop i1 i2
                          else print_endline "Failed with line from file1:";
                          print_endline string1;
                          print_endline " and from line 2:";
                          print_endline string2
    | exception End_of_file, exception End_of_file -> print_endline "Passed"
    | s, exception End_of_file -> if String.trim s = ""
                              then loop i1 i2
                              else print_endline "Failed"
    | exception End_of_file, s -> if String.trim s = ""
                              then loop i1 i2
                              else print_endline "Failed"
  in loop ic1 ic2
;;
```

This sort of structure worked when I had a single input channel, but now when matching on two input channels simultaneously, it throws the exception `Error: Exception patterns are not allowed in this position.`  Is there a way around this?  I've seen other ways of reading through a file that involve using `try ... with ...` but if possible I'd prefer to solve this with simple matching on `input_line ...`

Comment: How can you call String.trim and expect to match 2 file's contents?

Comment: @G4143 As I understand it `trim` will just remove trailing white space, so if the two lines are only off by a single space then I still want to say they're equal.  Perhaps this does something I don't expect though?

Comment: You should read the docs on String.trim"Return a copy of the argument, without leading and trailing whitespace. The characters regarded as whitespace are: ' ', '\012', '\n', '\r', and '\t'. If there is neither leading nor trailing whitespace character in the argument, return the original string itself, not a copy."

Comment: @G4143 My program seems to work when I use `trim` and the docstring says what I expected, mostly.  So I don't think there's any mistake here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap `input_line` in a function that converts the `exception` and return value into an `option`, you can pattern match on that:

```ml
let input_line_opt ch =
  try Some input_line ch with
  | End_of_file -> None

...

match (input_line_opt i1, input_line_opt i2) with
| Some string1, Some string2 -> ...
| None, None -> ...
| Some s, None -> ...
| None, Some s -> ...
```